# remove white space aside the dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I just wanted to copy some dropdown menu to other site of mine. but it seems i did something wrong, so all of my dropdown items have some white space aside them. (like the picture)
[white space side the dropdown items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnnm.png)

but in the first site i developed the code, this problem did not exist! (example)
[example of source code dropdown item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hit4J.png)

actually i mixed bootstrap and materialize to form the code (and i know this is a bad idea, but it worked last time for me).
I just don't know what to do, to remove the gap!
and this is part of my code:
`

```html
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'petrobavar/css/materialize.min.css' %} "
          media="screen,projection"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<nav class="mb-3">
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-1 amber-text darken-text-5" style="font-family: IRANSansWeb">
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="right sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <a href="{% url 'petrobavar:home' %}" class="left hide-on-large-only"><img
                src="{% static 'petrobavar/petrologo.png' %}" style="width: 5rem"></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li class="tab dropdown-trigger " data-target="dropdown6" style="text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);"><a href="#">ارتباط با
                ما</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="dropdown6" class="dropdown-content center-align" style="font-family: IRANSansWeb">
    <li><a href="{% url 'petrobavar:contact' %}" class="center-align">آدرس و تلفن های تماس</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
/* Dropdown list color */
.dropdown-content li > a, .dropdown-content li > span {
    background-color: #546e7a;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100% !important;

}</style>
```

`

Comment: just add `padding-right: 0` in `.dropdown-content` css

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-x: hidden;` on `.dropdown-content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please just add
 **padding: 0; 
width: auto !important;**
 
in **.dropdown-content** class in CSS file as below:

We have added padding and width in last line.

```css
.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Please try and let me know.

Comment: that was very helpful, thank you. actually I was changing padding, but it didn't work, but your hint work out very well.